# Creating advanced layout - Flexbox or Table

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I was trying to take an exercise and create an advanced layout as shown below.

After I came up with two solutions I started to wonder what is the best solution for creating such a layout.

Would you use flex display or table display? Would you consider using bootstrap or not? What should I consider when choosing one over the other in this case? Also taking in consideration devices with smaller resolution, for example 800px or less.

[image: An example of how the final result looks like]

Here are my implementations:

Flex implementation:

```
<div class="container p-0">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight">
          <div class="flex-grow-1 bd-highlight">
            <div class="mt-3 ml-3">
                #C0000028524
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-grow-10 bd-highlight d-flex long-title-container">
            <div class="mt-3 long-title">
                <p class="long-title mb-0 fs-5">
                    Context menu shows wrong language
                </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-grow-1 bd-highlight text-secondary">last updated</div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row bd-highlight">
          <div class="flex-grow-1 bd-highlight mlm-1">
            <img src="open.png" />
          </div>
          <div class="flex-grow-10 bd-highlight d-flex long-title-container"><p class="long-title">Context menu shows wrong language</p></div>
          <div class="flex-grow-1 bd-highlight text-secondary">last updated</div>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Link to the flex implementation: https://jsfiddle.net/7d512swt/

And here is my table implementation:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">          
        <div class="mt-3 ml-3">
                #C0000028524
        </div>
      </th>
      <td>              
        <p class="long-title mb-0 fs-5">
            Context menu shows wrong language
        </p>
    </td>
      <td>last updated</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td><img src="open.png" /></td>
      <td><p class="long-title">Context menu shows wrong language</p></td>
      <td>last updated</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Link to the table implementation:
https://jsfiddle.net/auv08hdq/

Comment: In my opinion `Table > Flex`

Comment: In your example the cells are not equal width, and one of bootstrap strengths is its 12 column layout that all have equal width so I wouldn't recommend bootstrap for that example.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.